# In an A.P , first term = 2 & sum of first 5 terms is 1/4th of sum of next five terms. Write the equation & find d.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

Q: In an A.P ,  first term = 2 & sum of first 5 terms is 1/4th of sum of next five terms. Write the equation & find d.

My solution:

$S_5$ =$\frac{1}{4}$*{$S_{10}$- $S_5$}. Q says that it is equal to sum of $\frac{1}{4}$ th of next 5 terms I.e summation of 6th , 7th , 8th , 9th , 10th term. It doesn’t not say it equals to $S_{10}$.

According to my textbook , Answer is :

$S_5$ = $\frac{1}{4}$ * $S_{10}$ .

How is this right ?

Comment: The equation $S_5 = \frac{1}{4}S_{10}$ is false since $S_5 \neq 0$, as you can verify by solving the problem.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Textbook solution says it’s correct. I’ll check it again. What do you think about the solution I have written ?

Comment: The equation $S_5 = \frac{1}{4}(S_{10} - S_5)$ is correct.  If you substitute $2$ for $a_1$ in the formulas $a_n = a_1 + d(n - 1)$ and $S_n = \frac{n(a_1 + a_n)}{2}$, you can apply the equation $S_5 = \frac{1}{4}(S_{10} - S_5)$ to find $d$.

Comment: Have you made progress?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Hii , wasn’t well. I confirmed the solution & the textbook solution is said to be correct & not the one I gave. That’s the trouble.

Comment: I hope you are feeling better.  I could not really follow the rest of your last comment.  Based on the statement of the question at the top of your post, I obtained $d = -6$, $S_5 = -50$, and $S_{10} = -250$.

Comment: The textbook is horribly wrong, and your interpretation is correct. That's why textbooks have to be careful at that level, I know in competitive books that they usually have like $35$ examples of the same concept to aid reinforcement, but too many examples leads to poor error checking. I used to have nightmares over these mistakes at that age.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Can you believe it is form NCERT (The national textbook) & still , till today has mistakes.

Comment: The NCERT? Oh, that's a shocker then. The NCERT is actually the best book of the lot : but the catch is that I haven't actually read NCERT books for classes 7 and above, so I don't know if they start to also look like any other competitive book. If this is happening in the NCERT book then other books will likely be worse.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer No , NCERT class 11 & 12 is horrible. I find ISC textbooks to be the best ones.

Comment: @S.M.T I see! I had no clue about that, if that's true then it's unfortunate because for classes 6 and below, NCERT has fantastic content. Actually, it's kind of unfortunate that NCERT needs to publish books for 11th and 12th standard kids. I'd rather they gave it a good go in the children segment and left the competitive segment to the boards and other private institutions. I was under the impression that those institutions do a worse job, but if that's not true then I would make such a suggestion to NCERT. Anyway, people at NCERT don't strike me as wanting to write competitive books.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Hmm , Yeah. NCERT should ask you to write competitive books. True.

Comment: @S.M.T I would be more interested to write content for grades 1-6, because I've had more contact with kids in my life than with people of grades 9 and above. I would write competitive books for ... money. Of course!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n$ be the nth term and d be the common difference. Then according to your question
\begin{align*}
S_5= 5a+10d = 1/4(5a+35d) \\
20a+40d = 5a +35d \\
a=2 \implies 40+40d = 10+35d \\
d= -6
\end{align*}

What has been written in your textbook maybe a typo and please check your calculations. It should be $S_{10}= 5S_5$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).